# I have the same answers on each Radio Button

Tags: java, android, arrays

I am trying to do a quizz app so I followed a tutorial this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3sDo9afuPOI and thanks to it a I made the quizz, but I have a slight problem is that for first question I have something like:

```
What is Spain capital?
Malaga
Madrid 
Barcelona
But for questions 2 and 3 and so on answers are like that 
What is France capital?
Paris
Paris1
Paris2
```

Here the part of code that actually does the work

```
if (flag < questions.length) {
                textviewquest.setText(questions[flag]);
                radiobtn1.setText(options[flag * 3]);
                radiobtn2.setText(options[flag * 3] + 1);
                radiobtn3.setText(options[flag * 3] + 2);
```

and flag is an integer initialized to 0 and I have 30 questions 
But I can't really figure out how to repair it.
I wish someone can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
 radiobtn1.setText(options[flag * 3]);
 radiobtn2.setText(options[flag * 3 + 1]);
 radiobtn3.setText(options[flag * 3 + 2]);
```

options[flag * 3] + 1 take the 'flag*3' element of options and concat with "1".

options[flag * 3 + 1] take the 'flag*3 + 1 ' element of options

Comment: Thank you man for your help , but i don't quite understand i thought options[0] would go for first radio button option and + 1 would give the second and + 2 would give the third , but the problem was in ] Thank you again